# 5.16 LAB: Adjust list by normalizing _ zybook - Java

Tags: java

5.16 LAB: Adjust list by normalizing
When analyzing data sets, such as data for human heights or for human weights, a common step is to adjust the data. This adjustment can be done by normalizing to values between 0 and 1, or throwing away outliers.

For this program, adjust the values by dividing all values by the largest value. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of floating-point values that follow. Assume that the list will always contain fewer than 20 floating-point values.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
System.out.printf("%.2f", yourValue);

Ex: If the input is:

5 30.0 50.0 10.0 100.0 65.0
the output is:

0.30 0.50 0.10 1.00 0.65
The 5 indicates that there are five floating-point values in the list, namely 30.0, 50.0, 10.0, 100.0, and 65.0. 100.0 is the largest value in the list, so each value is divided by 100.0.

For coding simplicity, follow every output value by a space, including the last one.

I have been confused about how to do floating-point values in arrays and loops as in my book it never went over that.

```
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  double numElements; 
  numElements = scnr.nextDouble(); 
  double [] userList = new double [numElements]; 
  int i; 
  double maxValue; 
  
  for (i = 0; i < userList.length; ++i) { 
     userList[i] = scnr.nextDouble(); 
  } 
  
  maxValue = userList[i]; 
  for (i = 0; i < userList.length; ++i) { 
     if (userList[i] > maxValue) { 
        maxValue = userList[i]; 
     } 
  } 
  
  for (i = 0; i < userList.length; ++i) { 
     userList[i] = userList[i] / maxValue; 
     System.out.print(userList[i] + " "); 
     System.out.printf("%.2f", userList[i]);
  }
```

}
}

It's outputting:

```
LabProgram.java:8: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
  double [] userList = new double [numElements];
```

I am confused about how to move forward, any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I am confused about how to move forward" To move forward, start by reading [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822. Make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We need a clear, *specific* question, that starts with your attempt to *read and understand* the error message. (Hint: what do you think is the type of `numElements`? Did you check that? What is the purpose of `numElements` in your program? Does the type *make sense*, given that purpose? In your own words, what is a `double`, and what is an `int`?)

Comment: Please try to make sure your question is focused on *the actual problem you are currently trying to solve* (i.e., the error message), *not* on the overall task of your code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Hi, sorry about that, I just posted that so it would make sense. The type of numElements is what the user input and it's for floating-point values. I am confused why it's saying error when I declared it as double and not int. Would I have to convert it as an int to a double?

Comment: "and it's for floating-point values" Yes; *that's the problem*. "I am confused why it's saying error when I declared it as double and not int." Because you *should neither declare it as double, nor read a double; you should declare an int and read an int*. Why? Because you want to *use that value to count the elements of an array*. (Right? That's why it's called `numElements`, i.e. "number of elements"? That's why it's used like `new double[numElements]`?) Does it make sense to use a floating-point number for this purpose? No, obviously not, right?

Comment: Oh!! That makes so much sense! I'm sorry I didn't understand first, they never really went over that because the array element number was always fixed. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also, I'm an idiot bc I didn't understand that the 5 was the number of elements, I thought it was part of the values.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the data type of numElements to int and the scanner command to int as well

Like this:

```
int numElements = scnr.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you end up figuring it out??? I have a solution for you. ---
There were a few adjustments I had to make. I used your code as a
blueprint, because I was stuck too, and I ended up getting it
right. --- Cheers.

```
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  int numElements; 
  numElements = scnr.nextInt(); 
  double [] userList = new double [numElements]; 
  int i; 
  double maxValue; 
  
  for (i = 0; i < userList.length; ++i) { 
     userList[i] = scnr.nextDouble(); 
   } 
  
  maxValue = userList[0]; 
  for (i = 0; i < userList.length; ++i) { 
     if (userList[i] > maxValue) { 
        maxValue = userList[i]; 
     } 
  } 
  for (i = 0; i < userList.length; ++i) { 
     userList[i] = userList[i] / maxValue; 
     System.out.printf("%.2f ", userList[i]);
   } 
 System.out.println();  
} }
```